# AMO-Assembly takes long to initialize when compiling for .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, ssas

I am developing a small application in c# to administrate Analysis Services cube partitions using the Analysis Services Management Object Model (AMO). Therefore, my application uses the assembly `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll` as it is deployed with SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012. When I set .net 4.0 or 4.5 as the target framework, everything works fine. However, the target system only has 3.5 available (We have to live with this), and when I set this as the target framework, the instruction

`Server OLAPServer = new Server();`

takes about 10 seconds. During this time, my application window freezes. Afterwards, I can successfully `.connect()` to my local SSAS instance.

It doesn't matter if I use the dll of SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012, the problem happens with both. When I change to target framework 4.0 or 4.5, the initialization is done in less than one second. If this matters, I am using Visual Studio 2012.

What is happening during this time? Can it be shortened while still using .net 3.5?

I could move the initialization to a separate thread to avoid that the window is going to freeze. But I would prefer a solution where it doesn't take so long to initialize.

Thanks for your help!